How to find next open accounting period in netsuite?
I have to find next open accounting period for certain period.
Suppose, on invoice, accounting period is Feb 2022, then first check if accounting period has closed. If closed, I have to find next open accounting period.
Is there saved search formula or any other approach please advice.

In my experience NetSuite itself will attempt to assign the closest open period to a transaction based on the transaction date.
e.g. If you are entering a vendor bill from 3 months ago you'd enter the correct date on the bill (now - 3 months) but only last month is still open NetSuite will assign last month as the accounting period.

This is correct. And in any case, if you wanted to move the Period to the next future Period anyway, just search for all Periods and set the transaction to use the next result in the list from the search.

If you prefer SQL this can get you started...
SELECT
  accountingperiod.id AS accountingperiod_id,
  MIN(startdate) AS min_startdate,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
    ORDER BY
      MIN(startdate) ASC
  ) AS rownum
FROM
  accountingperiod
WHERE
  1 = 1
  AND isinactive = 'F'
  AND closed = 'F'
  AND isyear = 'F'
  AND isquarter = 'F'
GROUP BY
  accountingperiod.id
ORDER BY
  min_startdate ASC
FETCH FIRST
  1 ROW ONLY

